# Entity DB Adding New User and Other Related Data to DB

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Hey. Nooby question but new with Entity.

I am trying to create a new user object and some details in some additional tables which have a foreign key of the newly created user id.

I've attempted to do this in one round trip. Do I have to add the user to the database first and then go back, set the userid's on the other objects and add them. Here is the Entity Model and code to elaborate:

[image]

```
            using (var context = new ServicesEntities())
        {
            newUser = new UsersTable();

            newUser.Address = user.UserDetails.Address;
            newUser.City = user.UserDetails.City;
            newUser.Country = user.UserDetails.Country;
            newUser.Email = user.Email.EmailString;
            newUser.FirstName = user.UserDetails.FirstName;
            newUser.LastName = user.UserDetails.LastName;
            newUser.State = user.UserDetails.State;
            newUser.Zip = user.UserDetails.Zip;

            context.UsersTables.AddObject(newUser);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        using (var context = new ServicesEntities())
        {                               
            var referralDetails = new UserReferrals();
            referralDetails.CreatedThruServiceId = 1; // todo don't make this an absolute 1
            referralDetails.ReferralEmail = user.ReferralDetails.ReferralEmail;
            referralDetails.TwoPlusTwoHandle = user.ReferralDetails.TwoPlusTwoHandle;
            referralDetails.UserId = newUser.UserId;               

            context.UserReferrals.AddObject(referralDetails);

            context.SaveChanges();           // THIS WORKS FINE!    
        }

        using (var context = new ServicesEntities())
        {
            var credentials = new UserCredentials();
            credentials.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
            credentials.EmailValidated = false;
            //credentials.EmailValidatedOn = null;
            credentials.FailedLoginAttempts = 0;
            credentials.IsLockedOut = false;
            //credentials.LastValidLogin = null;
            credentials.Password = user.Password.PasswordString;
            credentials.PermissionId = 1; // todo don't make this an absolute 1 = user
            credentials.SuccessfulLoginAttempts = 0;
            credentials.UserId = newUser.UserId;        ;

            context.UserCredentials.AddObject(credentials);

            context.SaveChanges(); // THIS ONE CRAPS OUT!
        }
```

When I run this I get the following Exception when I run SaveChanges():

> {"A dependent property in a
>   ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a
>   store-generated column. Column:
>   'UserId'."}

**Note: Updated this with some slightly different code based on an example in a book.**

**Note2: I've narrowed down the problem to be in the adding of credentials.**

**Note3: Fixed this, I accidentally had AUTO-INCREMENT set on my UserCredentials userid. If anyone ares here is working code:**

```
public POCO.User AddNewUserToDb(User user)
        {
           if (IsDuplicateUser(user.Email.EmailString))
            {
                throw new DuplicateNameException("This email is already taken.");
            }

            UsersTable newUser;

            using (var context = new ServicesEntities())
            {
                newUser = new UsersTable();

                newUser.Address = user.UserDetails.Address;
                newUser.City = user.UserDetails.City;
                newUser.Country = user.UserDetails.Country;
                newUser.Email = user.Email.EmailString;
                newUser.FirstName = user.UserDetails.FirstName;
                newUser.LastName = user.UserDetails.LastName;
                newUser.State = user.UserDetails.State;
                newUser.Zip = user.UserDetails.Zip;

                var referralDetails = new UserReferrals();
                referralDetails.CreatedThruServiceId = 1; // todo don't make this an absolute 1
                referralDetails.ReferralEmail = user.ReferralDetails.ReferralEmail;
                referralDetails.TwoPlusTwoHandle = user.ReferralDetails.TwoPlusTwoHandle;
                //referralDetails.UserId = newUser.UserId;

                var credentials = new UserCredentials();
                credentials.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
                credentials.EmailValidated = false;
                //credentials.EmailValidatedOn = null;
                credentials.FailedLoginAttempts = 0;
                credentials.IsLockedOut = false;
                //credentials.LastValidLogin = null;
                credentials.Password = user.Password.PasswordString;
                credentials.PermissionId = 1; // todo don't make this an absolute 1 = user
                credentials.SuccessfulLoginAttempts = 0;
                //credentials.UserId = newUser.UserId; ;

                newUser.Credentials = credentials;
                newUser.ReferralDetails = referralDetails;

                context.UsersTables.AddObject(newUser);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            user.UserId = newUser.UserId;

            return user;
```

Comment: So, you've attempted and what was the result you got? Did it work?

Comment: ah should've said. edited this with the details.

Comment: this is unbelieavably frustrating, all I want to do is add a user, credentials and referral details. I could do this in SQL no problem but entity is crapping out no matter what I do!

I can't even figure out how to add the user on one trip and then add the other stuff on another trip to the db. argh

Comment: it doesn't like the fact that my IDs are auto increment fields aka store generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add related records directly to UserTable record:

```
newUser.Credentials.Add(credentials);
newUser.ReferralDetails.Add(referralDetails);
```

Do not set any Id. It will be set during saving automatically.

**Edit:** Btw. make sure that UserId column in UserCredentials table is not set as auto generated in database.

Comment: attempted this a few times and it failed. i think i've narrowed down what the problem is.

Comment: phew, this was the problem. how frustrating that almost 3-4 hours were wasted based on this silly mistake by me! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these links:

[Using the entity framework to add existing entities to a collection on a newly created entity.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407712/using-the-entity-framework-to-add-existing-entities-to-a-collection-on-a-newly-cr)

[How to create foreign key relationships with the Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197747/how-to-create-foreign-key-relationships-with-the-entity-framework)

[Entity Framework - insert new object with a collection of existing objects](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/2470d3b8-fe6a-4b85-830f-2de23d52f5c8)

The key links for EF4:

> Fortunately, in EF4 we can directly
>   update the relationship due to the
>   Foreign Key Association which allows
>   us to keep the foreign key property
>   inside the entity classes.   For
>   detail, please see
>   http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2009/11/06/foreign-key-relationships-in-the-entity-framework.aspx.
>
> Besides, we have another great feature
>   Self Tracing Entities, which makes the
>   n-tier pattern much easier in EF,
>   http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2009/11/15/updated-feature-ctp-walkthrough-self-tracking-entities-for-the-entity-framework.aspx.

Comment: i think theres a better way to do this in EF4

Comment: I added a new link that points to a MSDN page. There you can find great links that will lead you in the right direction for EF4...

Comment: read thru all this stuff multiple times and still no luck. my OP has been updated to narrow down the problem to credentials

Answer (score 0):

EF4 will allow you to include the foreign key values as scalar properties of your entities.  Make sure the "Include foreign keys" checkbox is checked when you create your EDM.

Looking at your model, it looks like you've already done that.  Just set the foreign key values explicitly, no need to do a round trip.

Comment: yeah, but I can't set them explicitly because the id is generated by the sql db (its an auto incrememnt column)

Comment: I updated my original post which uncovers the error is somewhere in credentials.